# Configuring GTM to set a field on page view after the page has loaded

Tags: sharepoint, google-analytics, analytics, tracking, google-tag-manager

Maybe this isn't possible, but here's the situation.
I am trying to track user ID's on my sharepoint pages in google analytics, on page view. Because I have to use sharepoint's **SP.js** script to get the currently logged in user to retrieve their ID, I am using SP.SOD.**executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded** to run the part of my javascript that gets the user id and then pushes it to the dataLayer.
Unfortunately because of having to wait for the SP.js script to be loaded the userid value is pushed to the datalayer **after the GTM container** has loaded and so shows up as **undefined** in the **PageView** tag on Tag Manager.
I have thought about putting the GTM container into my script after it has obtained the user id, but I'm not sure what that means for the non-javascript part of the container:

`<noscript>`
`<iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>`
`</noscript>`

My work around has been to fire an event when I have the userid and send an event to Google Tag Manager, but this means that the userId shows up as an event and not as part of page view.

So is it possible to set a field in the Google Analytics Page View event after the tag manager container has loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is no. Once the page view is recorded, you cannot set a field for that same page view once tracking has occurred. What you are doing with events is exactly what you should be doing. The only other options you have are to delay recording the page view until your script finishes, but that means late-loading tags, hence a percentage of missed page views being recorded, or you could simply let the first page view be recorded without the user id, then set a cookie so it is recorded on all subsequent page views. An additional option, you could set the user id as a cookie on the browser for up to a year after the session starts. Then anytime that person comes back, you would conveniently already have the user id.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I like the idea of using cookies. Aside from the first pageview it would be pretty accurate at tracking users, but I think I would have to set the cookie on every page in case the session times out and they start browsing anonymously. But I can make that work. I also have one custom dimension of User Type that I could track the same way.
Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Sure thing. Whichever way you would like to set the cookie, remember that you do not always have to set it as a session cookie. You can set the expiration to a year from whenever the user hits a page and the cookie will still be there even if the session does time out.

Comment: One other piece of advice. You get better tracking if you take out all the async stuff in the tag and always load the tag as the first element of the body. The reason why is that asynchronous loaded tags might not trigger before the user is presented with content where he or she might click off the page. Third, put the image for the noscript inside a hidden image tag. Iframes are evil and VERY late-loading.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a Virtual Pageview and set a trigger when the user id is available but then this will increase the amount of Pageviews on your site.

How about moving the script above the GTM container? so that way the SP.js script loads first

Comment: The script is above the gtm container now, but because the user is retrieved async I have no way of knowing when I will have the value.

Comment: @Sky Please do not recommend double-counting page views. No matter how you look at it that is a bad practice.

Comment: I didn't recommend it. My advice was moving the script